# davfs unknown option because of secrets file

Tags: davfs2

I'm trying to make a WebDAV auto-mount on my machine.

I've installed `davfs2`, then copied `/etc/davfs2` to `~/.davfs2`. I added the WebDAV URL to `/etc/fstab`:

```
[URL of the WebDAV]   [Local folder]    davfs   rw,user,auto    0   0
```

I also added the username and password to `~/.davfs2/secrets` and uncommented `secrets ~/.davfs2/secrets` in `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf` to enable automatic login.

Now I can manually mount it by running `mount www.myserver.com` (it doesn't ask me for username/password). I understand that running `mount -a` will do the same thing that would've been done at boot, but when I run `sudo mount -a` as my user (just `mount -a` says I need to be root) I do get asked for a username/password.

I then uncommented `secrets ~/.davfs2/secrets` in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` to enable automatic authentication (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406782/auto-mount-webdav-folder) and [this](http://techiech.blogspot.ch/2013/04/mounting-webdav-directory-in-linux.html)). Now running `sudo mount -a` AND just using `mount` both result in `/sbin/mount.davfs:/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf:36: unknown option`. Line 36 is the `secrets ~/.davfs2/secrets` line.

Why does it say unknown option? How do I fix it?

Comment: One problem I had: When using the conf= option for `mount -o` the davfs.conf file needs to be given as parameter (with an absolute path to the secrets file!), not the secrets file itself.

Answer (score 9):

I have just sorted this out on a linux (mint 17.3) laptop.

There were two things contributing to my problem:

1. I had enabled ordinary users to use davfs. Leave the secrets line in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` commented out. This will force davfs to rely on the user specific configuration. I had both the global (/etc/davfs2/) and user (~/.davfs2/) configuration files both trying to do the job at the same time.

   1(a). you may need to uncomment the secrets line in `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf`. Mine is uncommented and works, but the default may work fine too. I have not tested it.
2. in `~/davfs2/cache/` the directory for my remote webdav connection cache had incorrect permissions - it needs to be set to 0700 (not just 700).

Comment: The 'secrets' line is not allowed in /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf, and this is why the error "unknown option" is thrown.  The 'secrets' line is allowed in *user* config files like ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf.  Just copy the stock /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf file to ~/.davfs2/ and uncomment the `secrets` line in ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf .

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I named the file `~/.davfs2/secret` instead of  `~/.davfs2/secrets`. I fixed this and now it works.

It seems that the error message is misleading, there's nothing wrong with the option.

Answer (score 0):

The correct file permission for secrets is `600`, execute the command `chmod 600 secrets`.